# Zeppelin log4j settings not printing the logs in console

Tags: log4j, amazon-cloudwatch, apache-zeppelin

I have a Zeppelin application that runs a daemon when I start that application, my logs are printing in the file but I not printing in the console. Below is my log4j properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, FILE, STDOUT, CONSOLE

# CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n



### Direct log4j properties to STDOUT ###  
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out  
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Configuration File
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/home/user/logs/log4j-test.log
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

I can see the logs in the file but not on the console, this application starts as a background application. I am running this application in AWS EC2, so I want to capture the logs in cloudwatch

P.S: As of now I am tailing **tail -200f /home/user/logs/log4j-test.log**, so I want to avoid this and use Console ogging settings

Comment: I am not sure if I am right, but I find two odd things here: 1. Your `CONSOLE` appender has no target attached. 2.You defined `stdout` appender, but you are trying to use `STDOUT` appender. So this is why I think your logs are not printed to console. Currently I am trying too to setup Log4j for Zeppelin in AWS EMR (and also to log to console) so if you found a solution here it is welcomed.